# how can I read and view an image form internet?

Tags: qt, qt4.7

[Here in this url an image which I want to read and view it in my program](http://zwjte.com/s/media/images/35ea10fc43.jpg)

here is the code I used to do that but I don't know how to complete :S

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://zwjte.com/s/media/images/35ea10fc43.jpg"));
    reply = manager->get(request);
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(ReadyRead()));
}
void MainWindow::ReadyRead()
{
    QByteArray bytes(reply->readAll());
    //??????????????????
}
```

Comment: I would mark some of your other questions as answered if they have been answered before asking any more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a `QImage` from a `QByteArray` with the [`QImage::fromData`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qimage.html#fromData-2) static method.

Once you have that, display it however you want. See the [Image viewer](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/widgets-imageviewer.html) example for instance.

Comment: I tried that but failed :( ...
There is no image appears ---------->
 void MainWindow::ReadyRead()
{
    QUrl l(reply->url());
    QByteArray bytes(reply->readAll());
    QImage image;
    image.loadFromData(bytes);
    QPixmap pix = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
    ui->graphicsView->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(pix));
}

Comment: As stated in the docs and in my question, `fromData` is a static function. It doesn't operate on an instance of `QImage`, so `image.loadfFromData(whatever)` is essentially a no-op: it doesn't change `image` at all. Use `QImage image = QImage::loadFromData(bytes);`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go : http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html#fromData-2

Comment: Link is broken. Please remove it. Thx.